# Category hierarchy : Math and computer science definition

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, hierarchical-data

I look for the computer science and mathematical definition of a category hierarchy.

As far as I could find, from a computer science poit of view, a categry hierarchy is a tree data structure where there is a hierchical order between a parent and its children. Is this definition exact and complete?

Also, from a mathematical (graph theory) point of view, a category hierarchy is a rooted tree and more preciesly an out-tree? Is there a more precise and complete mathematical definition?

Comment: You may want to ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.